# spring batch add new parameter to existing job parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have an interface implementation that maps my request to `JobParameters`

```
@Component("myMapper")
public class MyMapper implements RequestMapper {

    @Override
    public JobParameters map(Request request) {
        JobParametersBuilder parameters = new JobParametersBuilder();
        parameters.addString("name", request.getValue(NAME));
        parameters.addString("test", request.getValue(TEST));
        return parameters.toJobParameters();
    }
}
```

In my JobRunner class, I have to add an additional param that is not in Request Object before executing the job:

```
public Response runJob(final Request request, final String id) {
    Job job = getJob(request);
    JobParameters parameters = myMapper.map(request);

    //i want to add id to parameters
    JobExecution execution;

        execution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);

}
```

How can I add this new param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to add a parameter in `JobParameters` directly, you need to use `JobParametersBuilder`.

You need to construct `JobParametersBuilder` from existing `JobParameters` and add the parameter in builder and again get `JobParameters` from builder.

```
JobParameters parameters = myMapper.map(request);
JobParametersBuilder parametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder(parameters);
parametersBuilder.addString("id", id);
JobParameters newParameters = parametersBuilder.toJobParameters();
```